# Show only icons by default and show the tab names when hovered

Tags: r, shiny

Is there a way to show only icons at the sidebar and when the user hovers it then the side bar should reflect.

I tried to do this by below code but failed. Can anyone help?

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(plotly)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
#Add test
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinyBS)
library(shinyjs)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(collapsed = TRUE,
                            sidebarMenu(
                              menuItem("Victim", tabName = "victim"),
                              menuItem("Trafficker", tabName = "trafficker")
                            )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "victim",
            h2("Victim tab")
    ),
    
    tabItem(tabName = "trafficker",
            h2("Trafficker tab")
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Human Trafficking"),
    sidebar,
    body
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { 
    
    onevent("mouseenter", "sidebarCollapsed", removeCssClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse"))
    onevent("mouseleave", "sidebarCollapsed", addCssClass(selector = "body", class = "sidebar-collapse"))
    
  }
)
```

Comment: I did install plus package. But I am getting this error ````Error in dashboardPagePlus(header = dashboardHeaderPlus(enable_rightsidebar = TRUE,  : 
  could not find function "dashboardPagePlus"````

Comment: yes....................

Comment: Use `shinydashboardPlus::dashboardPage`